# Windows repeatedly delays keystrokes

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, delayed-execution

I have a really weird problem, and Googling didn't get me to an answer regarding what could be the cause or even a solution:

I am using a Windows PC with Windows 10 and an Apple Desktop Keyboard connected via USB.

The problem: When I type something – for example I could repeatedly press A in a random text field in any program, if it's a game or a Word document, I get delays in keystrokes. So, for example, I type AAAAA, and then while I keep typing A on the keyboard, nothing happens on the screen for nearly a second – then the "lost" A's appear all at once. This seems to happen in a period of maybe every five seconds or less. It's also not a complete freeze – mouse interaction and everything else performs completely normally. Changing the USB port doesn't make any difference, and I confirmed that the keyboard works completely fine with other systems – so it seems to be a software problem.

It's a really annoying thing!

Any ideas what I could search for or what I could do? Is there any known bug like this or any weird setting in Windows that could cause this?

Comment: A lot of times this is caused by sticky keys being turned on

Comment: Thx for the tip but I found this idea earlier and ensured that all sticky key options are turned off

Comment: It could also be caused by Windows being busy. For example, "user experience" data, advertising and other content is continually being sent and received in Windows 10. There are a number of privacy tools that turn off *some* of this traffic, such as ShutUp10. Try one of these tools to see if it reduces keypress latency.